# Woocommerce Rest API Parameter filter

Tags: wordpress, rest, ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic2

I am developing Ionic3 mobile app for e-commence web site  using Woocommerce  REST API.

This website contains different color shoes and bags I need to filter them respect to color using REST API.

I tried this way. But it returns all products .

```
http://www.example.com/wc-api/v1/products?color=black"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter product using this way.

```
http://www.example.com/wc-api/v2/products?filter[pa_color]=black
```

Can be used `pa_*` for filter product by attributes

First you need to make sure your woocommece version is grater than 2.5. Otherwise you can't use this.

[More](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#view-products-count) details